# biblatex destroys section numbering in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, numbering, appendices

Why does  the `\printbibliography` command destroy the appendix numbering?

In my example the section number jumps over a number and the subsection is always zero.

If you delete the command `\printbibliography` everything is fine.

compiled with:

```
pdflatex beamer.tex
biber beamer.bcf
pdflatex beamer.tex
```

**Example**:
**beamer.tex:**

```
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@online{test,
author = {example, mr},
title = {test title},
date = {2013-06-24},
url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[language=german,
            style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\begin{document}

\section{test1}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bal bla\cite{test}
\end{frame}

\section{test2}
\begin{frame}{\insertsectionnumber.~\insertsection}
 bla bla
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{Literatur}
\subsection{Literatur sub}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{\insertsectionnumber.\insertsubsectionnumber~
     \insertsection~\insertsubsection}
 \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A better title for your question would be "beamer destroys section numbering", since this has nothing to do with the `\appendix` command itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `\printbibliography` command creates a new section within the frame, which is not what `beamer` likes, since sectioning commands are supposed to be outside the frame. So you have to tell `biblatex` not to create a new section when it prints the bibliography.  You can do this by redefining the bib heading.  Add the following to your preamble after loading `biblatex`.

```
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{}
```

(Note that this has nothing to do with the `\appendix` command itself, which by default in `beamer` does relatively little.)