# Biblatex and Beamer create unwanted "References" in header

Tags: beamer, biblatex, cross-referencing

When using Biblatex with Beamer an unwanted "References" is added to all frame headers (not just the bibliography frame). Id like turn off this behavior, couldnt however find any hint. Curiously it only shows up after translating the document twice. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Nice MWE, for the future try to use an improved MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `\printbibliography` adds a new section, see [biblatex destroys section numbering in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120851) or [How to remove the link to the references in a beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231385). This can be avoided by using `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{}` or `\printbibliography[heading=none]` respectively.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{biblatex}

% See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120851
% or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231385
% \defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{} or
% \printbibliography[heading=none] (see below).

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Normal Section}
    \begin{frame}{Normal Frame}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{References}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Test}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[heading=none]
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]